# Why doesn't PowerShell show all trace information when using System.Diagnostic.Trace.Listeners?

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, .net-assembly, trace, powershell-ise

I am testing an assembly in PowerShell. A feature of the assembly is that it writes trace information using the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` technology. By adding a `ConsoleTraceListener` to the `Listener` collection my applications should be able to display all the messages sent to the tracing system.

This works in console applications and the Visual Studio output window. It even kind of works in PowerShell, except there is much less output. I suspect the issue is related to async operations but I don't really know.

```bsh
$dll = (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter 'mylib.dll' | select -First 1).FullName
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile($dll) | Out-Null

$listener = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Clear()
[System.Diagnostics.Trace]::Listeners.Add($listener)

$service = 'servicename'
[Team.Library.Project.Name]::MethodAsync($service).Result
```

The console version of this works as I would expect. All the trace information is displayed in the console. However this implementation (PowerShell) only displays a few lines and then returns my object.

This is what I get from console. This has all the information I want:

[image: Console application trace output.]

This is what I get from PowerShell. It has less information:

[image: PowerShell trace output.]

---

Addendum: I found actually that when executing the script in a console window or in a PowerShell console window the output behaves correctly. Only PowerShell ISE doesn't work correctly. Maybe this is not a PowerShell problem but an ISE bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and setup a TraceListener configuration for `pwershell_ISE.exe` and activate the `ConsoleTraceListener` directly. In addition, I would check with [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) if you see more output there. If yes, you should also redirect the DefaultTraceListener information to the ConsoleTraceListener or use a custom listener.